# Naming Boolean (bit) Values in a SQL db

Tags: sql, naming-conventions

The [AdventureWorks Data Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms124438(v=SQL.100).aspx) specifies that the `[EmailPromotion]` column in the `[Contact]` table is an `int` and that:

```
0 = Contact does not wish to receive e-mail promotions.
1 = Contact does wish to receive e-mail promotions.
```

and `[Employee].[CurrentFlag]` uses `bit` as follows:

```
0 = Inactive
1 = Active
```

My question has two parts:

- Is there a good reason to use the `int` datatype in place `bit` (both uses will be documented)?
- What naming conventions for boolean and boolean-like columns do you recommend? (e.g. IsActive, ActiveFlag, Active)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first part they are probably allowing for future status codes (although with that column name it is hard to imagine what that could be...).

You will find a lot of dissent on your second question, but I prefer `IsActive` as a name in this case. I find it reads well, and prevents double negatives in code that you would get if you used something like `IsInactive`.

Comment: +1 - IsActive is a good standard for that.  For the first part, you don't want to limit yourself to two options.  If you have different email lists down the road, you either make a new column or change all your downstream procs to accommodate a new data type, unless you plan well and use int :)

Answer (score 2):

Whatever floats your boat. The only important thing is naming convention and consistency across the database.

Using `int` for a flag isn't justified, I would've used `tinyint`, I hardly ever use `bit` at all, because I'm always open for all kinds of possibilities out there.

I usually name those columns `Active` (if there are only two statuses) and `StatusId` (if there is more than one status).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a good reason to use the int datatype in place bit (both uses will be documented)?

INT is consistently supported.  While BIT is becoming more common, I'll wager the support is just a mask for an INT column with a CHECK constraint.  There's a [good asktom question about why Oracle doesn't have a specific BIT/BOOLEAN data type](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:6263249199595)...

> What naming conventions for boolean and boolean-like columns do you recommend? (e.g. IsActive, ActiveFlag, Active)

Same as programming, they should be prefixed with "is" and when read, should present a yes/no question to infer the column is a boolean indicator.  So "isActive" would be my decision, but I would be probing to see if the situation didn't require a STATUS table & foreign key.